# Weird awk behaviour , $1 is printed but $0 is not?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk

This is printed fine `ls | xargs -I var sh -c 'echo var | awk "{print $1}"'`

while this is not `ls | xargs -I var sh -c 'echo var | awk "{print $0}"'`

Obviously this is not my use case and is just to reproduce the problem.

So while $0 stands for complete line, it is weird for $0 to not print while $1 gets printed.

Reference OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this in the first place. You have an XY problem, where you assume that reading from the output of `ls` is the right way to accomplish some task.

Comment: Sure, this was just to reproduce the problem. And in my case I am using `find`.

Comment: You don't use `find` like this either, for the same [reasons you don't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: oh, I see now when I have read the article. And I  also found the solution to use `find` safely in the same article. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use:

```
ls | xargs -I var sh -c 'echo var | awk "{print $0}"'
```

That has `$0` in double quotes hence `$0` gets expanded by shell which is in this case has value `sh` without quotes. `awk` treats it as a variable and prints blank.

To make it work escape the `$`:

```
ls | xargs -I var sh -c 'echo var | awk "{print \$0}"'
```

**Why `$1` works:**

```
ls | xargs -I var sh -c 'echo var | awk "{print $1}"'
```

`$1` also gets expanded by shell and it is empty. Hence `awk` just executes an empty `print` which is equivalent of `print $0` and you get filename in output.

However it is not a good idea to use awk command in double quotes and parsing `ls` output is error prone.

Answer (score 1):

For others landing here: If your syntax was perfect but you are potentially using windows files, remember the `\r` will effectively overwrite your text and make it seem like `$0` is blank....

First run `dos2unix <file>`, then try your `awk`.

Note: removing `\r` with `sed` or `tr` isn't enough